# c++ half even rounding to x digits

Tags: c++, rounding, bankers-rounding

Given a float, I want to round the result to 4 decimal places using half-even rounding, i.e., rounding to the next even number method. For example, when I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    float x = 70.04535; 
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4) << x << std::endl;
}
```

The output is `70.0453`, but I want to be `70.0454`. I could not find anything in the standard library, is there any function to achieve this? If not, what would a custom function look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you use `float`, you're kind of screwed here. There is no such value as `70.04535`, because it's not representable in IEEE 754 binary floating point.

Easy demonstration with Python's `decimal.Decimal` class, which will try to reproduce the actual `float` (well, Python `float` is a C `double`, but it's the same principle) value out to 30 digits of precision:

```
>>> import decimal
>>> decimal.Decimal(70.04535)
Decimal('70.0453499999999991132426657713949680328369140625')
```

So your actual value doesn't end in a 5, it ends in 49999... (the closest to `70.04535` a C `double` can get; C `float` is even less precise); even banker's rounding would round it down. If this is important to your program, you need to use an equivalent C or C++ library that matches "human" (base-10) math expectations, e.g. `libmpdec` (which is what Python's `decimal.Decimal` uses under the hood).

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone can improve this, but it gets the job done.

```
double round_p( double x, int p ){                                        
    double d = std::pow(10,p+1);                                          
    return ((x*d)+5)/d;                                                   
}                                                                         
void main(int argc, const char**argv){                                    
    double x = 70.04535;                                                  
    {                                                                     
        std::cout << "value " << x << " rounded " << round_p(x,4) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "CHECK " << (bool)(round_p(x,4) == 70.0454) << std::endl; 
    }                                                                     
}
```